# Xamarin.Forms - View-To-View Bindings In C# Code?

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, xamarin, xamarin.forms

The Xamarin website has a [section on View-To-View Binding](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/#View-to-View_Bindings), but the examples are in XAML, using the `x:Reference` markup extension. How can I do the same thing in C# code?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it effectively the same way as the XAML example simply by setting your view's BindingContext to the other view.

Example:

```
var stepper = new Stepper();

var label = new Label {
    BindingContext = stepper
};
label.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty, new Binding ("Value", stringFormat: "{0:F0}"));
```

Alternatively, you can set the Binding.Source:

```
var stepper = new Stepper();

var label = new Label();
label.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty, new Binding ("Value", stringFormat: "{0:F0}", source: stepper));
```

[Source](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/41751/how-can-i-bind-view-to-view-using-code-not-xaml)

Answer (score 2):

`x:Reference` is just setting a reference to an object as `BindingContext` of another object.

This is basically:

```
myLabel.BindingContext = mySlider;
```